# Understanding Kafka consumer poll behaviour

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a consumer that polls records from a Kafka topic, and I am doing the following:

1. Assign the consumer to a specific partition in a kafka topic.
2. Seek to a specific offset in the past (so definitely there are records to poll).
3. I am executing the following code:

```
while (true) 
{
    ConsumerRecords<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> items= 
    consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(300));
    log.info("Polled {} items", items.count());
}
```

I get the following log:

```
Polled 0 items                                                                                                                      
Polled 0 items                                                                                                                      
Polled 0 items
Polled 0 items            
.
.
.                                                                                                          
Polled 0 items
Polled 3620 items
```

I just wanted to understand the behavior of the poll and why it got the 0 messages for many tries then it got the records at a later point in time? (remember I seeked to an offset which is in the past).

This is my consumer configuration:

```
{
  schema.registry.url=https://schema-registry.*********,
  enable.auto.commit=false,
  max.poll.records=65536,
  group.id=**************,
  fetch.max.wait.ms=5000,
  bootstrap.servers=********
  fetch.min.bytes=1048576,
  fetch.max.bytes=1048576,
  auto.offset.reset=earliest
}
```

Comment: Please add your consumer configurations too.

Comment: already did, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You should try printing what offsets are actually being consumed to verify the seek worked.

You shouldn't need to seek anywhere, unless you're re-using a `group.id` (and committing offsets somewhere in that loop) each run since you are setting `auto.offset.reset=earliest`.